# Arnold's ODE Ch. 2.3 exercise 2: Uniqueness proof for one-dimensional autonomous ODE, with field having discontinuous derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem of the title asks to prove the following: consider the one-dimensional autonomous ODE:
$$x'(t)=v(x(t))$$

and $x(t_0)=x_0$. We assume that $v:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $U$ is an open interval, $v$ is differentiable, but crucially $v'$ can be discontinuous. Also, $x_0\in U$. The goal is to show that the ODE has a unique solution in the following sense: there exists $x:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $I$ is an open interval containing $t_0$, and $x(t)$ satisfies the ODE and the intial condition. Furthermore, any other $y:I'\ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying these requirements, agrees with $x$ on an open interval containing $t_0$.

Now, in the theory of this chapter, Arnold proves the existence part. He also proves the uniqueness part under the assumption that $v$ is continuously differentiable. So, what needs to be done here is to remove the assumption that $v'$ is continuous.

I know how to do this under the additional assumption that $v'$ is locally bounded at $x_0$. This way we have that $v$ is locally Lipschitz which is all we need to show uniqueness. Any suggestion on how to remove this assumption?

Comment: Maybe of some use? https://mathoverflow.net/q/55289/31729